# How to search for an item and select it in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to search for a value in a cell in a spreadsheet and select it. Here is some pseudocode for what I want to do:

```
search for the unique value "Justin123" in spreadsheet
select the cell that contains the value "Justin123"
offset 2 cells to the left of the searched value and replace with new value "John123"
```

I tried to google a solution but all I found were recommendations on using the record macro feature to search and replace an item. However, what I need to do is slightly different since I need to search and replace the item two units to the left of the searched cell.

Comment: You can use `Find()` in VBA to locate the cell, then `Offset()` to modify the cell to the left of the found cell.

Comment: you have pseudo code, why don't try to "record macro" in excel? it should give you some idea of how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if you understand this code (hope it gets you interested in learning VBA):

```
Sub TestReplace()
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="Justin123", LookAt:=xlPart).Offset(0,-2).Value = "John123"
End Sub
```

The Macro Recorder is a great tool for beginners. Please do use it for simple cells operations.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I did try to use the macro recorder. Here are the steps that I followed: I pressed the Record Macro button, Ctrl+F Justin123 (this would move the selection box to the cell), and finally I stopped recording. However, upon looking at the contents of the new macro, it did not select anything let alone search for the item.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what you have to do is initialise a RANGE object (which represents a cell in excel). Then you set the range object to the output of the function `.Find()`, which returns a range object from the sheet that matches the search inputs. If there is no match, it sets the range object to `Nothing`. You can then use the method `.Offset()` that range objects have to traverse across the other range objects in the sheet.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:= "Justin123", LookAt:= xlPart)

    ' Check if rng is not Nothing [ie a match was made using .Find()]
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.Offset(0, -2).Value = "John123"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation of this code.